# How can I use the control key as a wxWidgets accelerator on a Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, wxwidgets

wxWidgets seems biased towards Windows, as 'Ctrl' binds to the control key on a Windows machine, but is converted to the command key on a Mac.

```
menuFile->Append(CONNECT_KEYSTROKE, wxT("&Connect\tCtrl-R"));
```

The code above shows up as ⌘R in your menu.

How do you bind to the control key on a Mac?

Comment: While it can be done, as your own answer shows, shortcuts with only Ctrl and a letter are very uncommon in native Mac apps. (And at least Ctrl-A and Ctrl-E are reserved for other purposes.) wxWidgets tries to help with making your app behave in a native app should by converting Ctrl to Cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'RawCtrl'

```
menuFile->Append(CONNECT_KEYSTROKE, wxT("&Connect\tRawCtrl-R"));
```

The code above shows up as ^R in your menu.

Comment: IMHO, *this* is being 'biased towards Windows', as now your app on Mac behaves like a Windows app, disregarding usual conventions of how Mac apps should behave.

Comment: That keyboard shortcut was just an example. In reality, I was trying to do something like ^⌘R, which you used to not be able to do in wxWidgets. Also, their documentation doesn't mention RawCtrl—I had to dig through the source code to find it. Hence, biased towards Windows.